# How is memory allocated for "new Integer(1)" in Java?

Tags: java, memory-management

I am little bit confused with java's memory allocation technique. Can anybody help me, how java will allocate memory for following code ?

```
Integer a;
a = new Integer(1);
```

I am asking that for `Integer a`, jvm will create 64 bit reference and `a = new Integer(1)`  for that it will allocate more memory to store value of 1. Is this correct ?

Comment: For Integer type there is a cactch. Integer objects up to 128 are created in advanced and cached. `new Integer` will create a new object, but preferred `Integer.valueOf` will return Integer object from cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most JVMs (even 64-bit ones) use 32-bit references. (Newer JVMs uses 32-bit references for heaps up to almost 32 GB) The reference is on the stack or in a CPU register and is not usually counted.  The Integer is allocated on the heap.

```
Integer i = new Integer(1); // creates a new object every time.
Integer j = 1; // use a cached value.
```

Using auto boxing is not only shorter, but can be more efficient as it can use a cache.

Of course the most efficient is

```
int k = 1; // not object created and no heap used.
```

For autoboxed values the performance difference is very small compared with primitives and the reference is likely to be the same size as the `int` value.  However for larger values, there can be a significant performance difference.

Answer (score 9):

`Integer a;` will allocate memory in stack to hold the reference value and initialized with `null`

`new` creates instance in heap memory

Comment: OK. So, in total it will allocate nearly 64+32 bits in memory. Is this correct ? 64 bit jvm

Comment: Yes, if you want to measure the object size then check [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

Comment: Won't it take much more memory, because we are using a class instead of the primitive? Doesn't allocate the JVM extra memory for storing private data like information about RTTI etc?

Comment: Not sure, if you want to measure the object size then [check this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)